# Run time exception "Conversion from string to type 'Boolean' is not valid." in LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am getting the above error. I am not able to retrieve the results of the query. The error happens in for each statement. Below is the code. I am learning LINQ and running the code from 
https://dotnetfiddle.net/#
Below is the code

```
Imports System
Imports System.Linq
imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Module Module1

    public class test

        public count as integer

        public grp1 as string

        public grp2 as String

        public sub new(ByVal cnt as integer, ByVal g1 as string, ByVal g2 as String)
            count = cnt
            grp1 = g1
            grp2 = g2
        end sub
    end class

    Public Sub Main()
        Dim list = New List(Of Tuple(Of Integer, string, String))
        list.Add(New Tuple(Of Integer, string, String)(5, "xxx", "green"))
        list.Add(New Tuple(Of Integer, string, String)(5, "yyy", "blue"))
        list.Add(New Tuple(Of Integer, string, String)(20, "aaa", "orange"))
        list.Add(New Tuple(Of Integer, string, String)(20, "aaa", "yellow"))
        list.Add(New Tuple(Of Integer, string, String)(20, "ccc", "magenta"))
        ' Group tuples by their first item.
        ' ... TupleGroup is an identifier name.
        Dim result = From v In list Group By v.Item1, v.Item2 Into Group, cnt = count(v.Item3) select new test(cnt, Item1, Item2)
            ' Loop over each group and its items. ERROR OUT
        For Each value In result

        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `cnt = count(v.Item3)` you don't need to provide a parameter to this function, because the data that you are using is already grouped.

Change

```
Dim result = From v In list Group By v.Item1, v.Item2 _
    Into Group, cnt = count(v.Item3) select new test(cnt, Item1, Item2)
```

to

```
Dim result = From v In list Group By v.Item1, v.Item2 _ 
    Into Group, cnt = count() select new test(cnt, Item1, Item2)
```

Comment: Thank you. I see the mistake now :)